# Custom UITableViewCell for Settings-like application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, settings, subclass

I'd like to have a settings view in my app. I want to have things like UILabels, UISwitches etc. (Like in the Settings app.)

How can I go about doing that? Can I just replace the detailView with the required view, or is there more to it then that? That may not work because I need to be able to set and get text values too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this project](http://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit/tree/master/InAppSettingsKitSampleApp/).

If you want to do it yourself, you can e.g. attach your own views to the cell's contentView, or use the accessory view to display your switches etc.

Comment: 90% of the settings app can be constructed using just the accessory view. and built-in table cell types.

Comment: And then I can set the delegate of the object as `self` to store settings changes, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You just add your custom views as subviews to the cells content view. Heres an example with an image view:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage.png"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```